# spring cloud config searchPaths

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm looking at implementing the 12factor approach to externalising config via Spring Cloud Config but am not able to get the wildcards working using searchPaths as I expected.

The documentation http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_server mentions that wildcards  {application}, {label}, {profile} can be used within the searchPaths variable so that *"you can segregate the directories in the path, and choose a strategy that makes sense for you (e.g. sub-directory per application, or sub-directory per profile).*"

I'm looking to have a single git repo, with either subdirectories per profile (and then per app, or subdirectory per app (then by profile).

e.g.

```
    spring:
      cloud:
        config:
          server:
            git:
              uri: https://stash.xxx.com.au/scm/xxx/config
              searchPaths: {application}
or
              searchPaths: {profile}
or
              searchPaths: {application}/{profile}
```

However when I use any of the wildcards {application} or {profile} in my searchPaths it doesn't find the data in the git repo, or for the concatenated option fails to startup at all.

Does anyone have a working example of this I can refer to?
Cheers
Roy

Comment: You didn't say what version of spring cloud config you are using (this is a recent feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually none of the examples in the user guide show the pattern being used in a list of `searchPaths`. I don't think that feature is supported with the GIT backend (but `{application}` is effectively the default in the filesystem backend, i.e. the one that works in the "native" profile).

Comment: Thanks Dave. You're right. I mis-read the guide. It mentions that for 'native' we can use spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations with placeholders,  and in the previous section there is also examples of searchPaths for file based repos. I assumed these were the same thing as they are both local file based but looks like they are treated differently.

Comment: I suppose it's a reasonably good idea to add placeholders to the search paths in VCS repos as well. Feel free to open an issue in GitHub.

Answer (score 10):

Use single quote and it works fine.

```
searchPaths: '{application}'
```

Hope this helps if someone stumbles across this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be useful to post our configuration, since it demonstrates the priority order of multiple search paths. The native backend `search-order` property is documented pretty well, but it wasn't clear to me that git backend `search-paths` works the same way.

This is with Spring Cloud release train 2020.0.2:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: /path/to/git/repo
          search-paths:
            - /defaults
            - "env_{profile}"
```

Properties found at later search-paths override ones found earlier.

Example of use:

- We default SQL logging = true for all services and environments in `defaults/application.yml`. So it's effective in TEST, QA, and UAT.
- We could override the default for a specific application in `defaults/specific_app_name.yml` (we don't for SQL logging).
- In production we turn off all SQL logging, in  `env_prod/application.yml`.
- If needed we can turn SQL logging on for a single production service, by adding the property to `env_prod/specific_app_name.yml`.

(Edit: I originally posted 4 search-paths above, but I realized that the last two are not needed for this example, and in fact we've never needed them in practice so I am removing them from our code even as we speak.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above, and more importantly if you want your common configuration (e.g. application.yml) which is shared across multiple applications per environment, to be read. Then place application.yml in a folder (say - common), then the config goes like this:

```
searchPaths:
  - '{application}'
  - common
```

{application} resolves to the value of 'spring.application.name' in the config clients' bootstrap.yaml.

Reference: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_placeholders_in_git_search_paths