# Spring clould config server directory organization with searchPaths not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

The company I'm working at has decided to centralize all of the configuration properties of our SpringBoot Projects in a single place. To do that, we configured a `spring-cloud-config-server` pointing to a Github repository.

On github, we created a folder for each application we have. Example:

```
-https://github.com/myusername/my-spring-cloud-config-repo (Github's base folder)
    --my-project-1 (folder)
        ---my-project-1.properties (file)
        ---application-dev.properties (file)
        ---application-prod.properties (file)
    --my-project-2 (folder)
        ---my-project-2.properties (file)
        ---application-dev.properties (file)
        ---application-prod.properties (file)
        ---application-test.properties (file)
```

Initially, the `application.properties` on our `spring-cloud-config-server` had the following configurations:

```
server.port=9090
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/myusername/my-spring-cloud-config-repo.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=myusername
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=mypassword
spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.force-pull=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths=*/**
```

Therefore, once we start the server, we could send the HTTP Request:

```
http://localhost:9090/my-project-2/test
```

and it would successfully return all the configurations on `my-project-2.properties` and `application-test.properties` inside the `my-project-2` folder, and this was the desired behaviour.
The problem begins when we send:

```
http://localhost:9090/my-project-2/dev
```

as it would return all the configurations on `my-project-2.properties` and `application-dev.properties` inside the `my-project-2` folder but also the `application-dev.properties` file from the `my-project-1` folder too. This happens because `searchPaths=*/**` forces the config server to search for the "dev" file on ALL folders of the repository and it would eventually cause conflicts every time a client starts up.

To fix that, according to [Here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html) and [Here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/), I could use `wildcards` on `searchPaths` configuration:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths={application}/{profile}
```

But it did not work... I also tried many combinations:

```
searchPaths={application}/{profile}.properties
searchPaths={application}/**
searchPaths=/{application}/{profile}
searchPaths='{application}/{profile}'
searchPaths='{application}/{profile}.properties'
searchPaths='{application}'/'{profile}'
```

(I tried the single quote idea based on the answer to [spring cloud config searchPaths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49794958/8007713))

But none of them worked for me. How should I configure the `searchPaths` property to make it work for my desided purpose? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the property is written `search-paths` and not `searchPaths`.

See also [the spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_pattern_matching_and_multiple_repositories).